# Is it possible to read and write from/to file opening it only once?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

is it possible to read and write from/to file using only 1 assign()?

I mean something like:

```
assign(fl, 'file.txt');
reset(fl) 
// I know, that when I use reset - I have only read permission, 
// but is there any other option to read and write opening the file only once?
read(fl, variable);
write(fl, 'asdf);
close(fl);
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, since you don't describe what FL's type is. If it is text(file), there is no such way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Reset` does not give you only read access; the default is read/write (`FileMode = 2`), at least in Delphi's Pascal, and FP is pretty compatible with it.

From the help topic on [`FileMode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.FileMode) (**emphasis mine**):

> Indicates the access mode on typed and untyped files opened by the Reset procedure.
>
> In Delphi code, FileMode determines the access mode to use when typed and untyped files (not text files) are opened using the Reset procedure.
>
> The file open modes that can be assigned to the FileMode variable are defined in the Constants list on System.SysUtils. **The default FileMode is 2 (Read/Write access).** Assigning another value to FileMode causes all subsequent Resets to use that mode.

Comment: Note the "NOT textfiles". And he writes text using writeln in the example. Moreover filemode is sharing behaviour, and thus doesn't apply to read/write with the same handle.

Comment: @Marco: That's a good catch, but there's no indication (other than the filename) that the file was opened as a `TextFile`. (The declaration of `f1` is missing, which would determine which type of file it is, and text files are usually (but not always) written to and read from using `WriteLn` and `ReadLn`.) You're probably right, though. Again, nice catch. :-)

Comment: If you are terribly bored, I can get you a job as FPC bug triager :-) Anyway the main point is that sharing mode read/write and file type level read/write are two different things

Comment: @Marco: :-) Now you've confused me. The question asked nothing about file sharing, and my answer said nothing about it either. The question was reading/writing to a file (the opening mode), which is exactly what `FileMode` does. (IMO, the poster shouldn't be using `Assign` anyway; stream-based file operations are much easier and safer, and support modern character sets.)

Comment: Since he write()s a string, it could only be file of shortstring (or some constant array of char maybe). As far as filemode goes, I don't know what I was thinking. Maybe filemode in the tfilestream.create got me mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

As your question was general, you didn't say what kind of data would be stored in the file. If you define your file as 'file of TRecord' (you'd have to define your record type first), then first you 'reset' the file to open it; afterwards, you can use the predefined procedure 'seek' to find a specific record within the file, read the data into a local variable of type TRecord, alter that record then write it back to the file. The file's current location will be that of the record that you have just read.

Reading and writing text files is more tricky - there exists the predefined procedure 'append', which allows one to add text to the end of the file (but not in the middle).

Thirty years ago, I used to use such a system in order to create my own databases; fortunately, database programming is much simpler now.